# FTP corrupts files after certain delay and/or size

Tags: php, ftp

i am building a few Excel files with PHPExcel and store them on the server running the script.
This part works well.

i then try to send them to my client's ftp server using ftp_put, but the files arrive corrupted to the server.

When opening them after downloading them back from the ftp server with Filezilla, i get an error saying that there is a problem with the content of the file and that they can try to repair it as much as they can if i wish so. Doing so doesn't help.

**if the excel file is under 100-120k its sent uncorrupted, bigger than that it gets corrupted.**

script to send via ftp

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($hostFTP);
if($login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $userFTP, $passwordFTP))
{
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
    if(ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_path.$output_filename, $localPath.$output_filename, FTP_BINARY))
    {
        $log = new Logs("listes.log", "Uploaded $output_filename");
    }
    else
    {
        $log = new Logs("listes.log", "FAIL Uploading $output_filename");
    }
    ftp_close($conn_id);
}
```

Am i doing something wrong? what can i do?

edit :

comparing the files in text show some differences starting at line 231, which i assume is around the 100-120k mark

tried with an image(jpg) and it also gets corrupted (top of image is fine, but at a point it just corrupts and the rest of the image is pretty much single colored), so problem isnt with excel;

Is it possible that the server (opensuse) limits ftp? and if so how?

Comment: What happens if you manually upload one of these, over 120k, files to the FTP server? Have you tried `FTP_ASCII` instead? Try manually using both ASCII and BINARY mode when manually uploading the files.

Comment: if you mean uploading manually with filezilla, the answer is the files are not corrupted, if you mean manually via a script, it gets corrupted in either ascii or binary

Comment: Yes, you've answered my questions completely. Using `ftp_put();`, can you try uploading an excel file created in Excel? Or maybe even try sending a txt file bigger than 120k via `ftp_put` and when you re-download it from the FTP server maybe an error in the text will make itself evident.

Comment: Also, is `ftp_pasv()` necessary? Try using/not using it

Comment: Are the Excel files over 120k opening without issue if you save them locally to your web server somewhere?

Comment: excel files over 120k open correctly when they are created on locel server.

Comment: txt files are not corrupted upon ftp transfer;

comparing the files in text show some differences starting at line 231, which i assume is around the 100-120k mark.

Comment: If you could, please update your question with the findings from the text file differences.

Comment: ftp script with files created from excel and not from my script are also corrupted.

Comment: Try doing 2 `ftp_put`s, of exactly the same file, one directly after the other, the first one to save as `file1` the second one to save as `file2` then `diff` them on the server and see if they are identical. That should tell you if it is random data loss or systematic errors always at the same point.

Comment: files are different, both corrupted, but at different lines

Comment: ftp_pasv() is necessary, otherwise i get empty AND corrupted files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i've found the problem, its not the code. its the internet service. We changed the internet provider yesterday and the ftp now works fine. I guess the ftp connection was being interrupted with the previous provider.